# XSLT grouping and leaving out duplicates

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon, xslt-grouping

I have the following XML input file:

```
<mappings>
    <mapping>
        <key>6718</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Info Page</value>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <key>35905</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Press releases</value>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <key>6718</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Info Page</value>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <key>36941</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Press releases</value>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <key>24920</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Press releases</value>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <key>40244</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Press releases</value>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <key>36639</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Press releases</value>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <key>1861</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Press releases</value>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <key>2280</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Press releases</value>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <key>42062</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Press releases</value>
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```

I would like to produce the following XML:

```
<reductions>
    <reduction>
        <group>Info Page</group>
        <key>6718</key>
    </reduction>
    <reduction>
        <group>Press releases</group>
        <key>35905</key>
        <key>36941</key>
        <key>24920</key>
        <key>40244</key>
        <key>36639</key>
        <key>1861</key>
        <key>2280</key>
        <key>42062</key>
    </reduction>
</reductions>
```

So the keys from the input XML need to be grouped in the output XML based on the value of the value node from the input XML.
Also the duplicates need to be removed, the input XML contans the key with value 6718 twice, the output XML only once.

I'm using XSLT 2.0 with Saxon 9 HE.
Can someone please help me?
[EDIT]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform 
    version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="mappings">
            <mappings>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="resource/R"/>
            </mappings>
        </xsl:variable>
        <reductions>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$mappings/*"/>
        </reductions>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="R">
        <mapping>
            <key><xsl:value-of select="MT[@N='content_id']/@V"/></key>
            <value>
                <xsl:attribute name="attribute">content_type</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="MT[@N='content_type']/@V"/>
            </value>
        </mapping>
        <!--mapping>
            <key><xsl:value-of select="MT[@N='content_id']/@V"/></key>
            <value>
                <xsl:attribute name="attribute">modified_timestamp</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(MT[@N='modified_timestamp']/@V, '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')"/>
            </value>
        </mapping-->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mapping">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="." group-by="value">
            <reduction>
                <group><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></group>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/key" group-by=".">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </reduction>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a stylesheet using `for-each-group` twice:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="mappings">
  <reductions>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="mapping" group-by="value">
      <reduction>
        <group><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></group>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/key" group-by=".">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </reduction>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </reductions>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[edit]
When I run the posted stylesheet with Saxon 9.4 HE against the input

```
<mappings>
    <mapping>
        <key>6718</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Info Page</value>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <key>35905</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Press releases</value>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <key>6718</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Info Page</value>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <key>36941</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Press releases</value>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <key>24920</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Press releases</value>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <key>40244</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Press releases</value>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <key>36639</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Press releases</value>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <key>1861</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Press releases</value>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <key>2280</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Press releases</value>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <key>42062</key>
        <value attribute="content_type">Press releases</value>
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```

I get the result

```
<reductions>
   <reduction>
      <group>Info Page</group>
      <key>6718</key>
   </reduction>
   <reduction>
      <group>Press releases</group>
      <key>35905</key>
      <key>36941</key>
      <key>24920</key>
      <key>40244</key>
      <key>36639</key>
      <key>1861</key>
      <key>2280</key>
      <key>42062</key>
   </reduction>
</reductions>
```

which is correct as far as I understand your requirements.

Comment: This is not the expected result. I get just as many <reduction> nodes as <mapping> nodes in the input, each having exactly one <group> and one <key> element. They're not grouped at all.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why you would get that result. I tested with Saxon 9.4 and the output I have now included in my answer seems to be what you want. Please provide details of the XSLT 2.0 processor you use and whether there are any details like namespaces in the input you have left out in your posting.

Comment: When I run command line it works, but when called from a Java application it doesn't work..

Comment: That's odd, have you written the code for the Java application following the guidelines on http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xsl/embedding.xml? Are you sure it is the same input document you process from the command line and from the application?

Comment: I've attached my XSL which I'm using, it's slight different but I can't see why it's not working.

Comment: Well, you have put the first `for-each-group` in the wrong place, you want to group the `mapping` child nodes of the `mappings` element, yet in your code you are trying to apply the grouping to each single `mapping`. So use the code I posted, with the 'for-each-group` done in the template matching `mappings`, not in the template matching `mapping` as then you do not have the grouping population you need.